# Determine which session manager restored Konsole a script is running under

Tags: linux, terminal, kde, konsole

If you log out of a KDE session with any [Konsole](http://userbase.kde.org/Konsole) terminals still open, they'll be there when you log back in (unless you've configured KDE otherwise).  How can any scripts running under these different terminals distinguish which terminal they're running under?

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's asking about konsole sessions, not terminals.  The terminal is a different thing, identified by the humble `tty` command of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell running in each terminal will have the environmental variable `SHELL_SESSION_ID` set to a unique identifier which persists across KDE sessions.

```
# echo $SHELL_SESSION_ID
ab9ed70bf9de40008c1955f5019e0671
```